# xib loaded but previous view controller not loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I have created an app using tab based application.By selecting a button in first view controller.xib image in second view controller.xib have to load.I have got the second view controller.xib but the problem is if i select first tab it not getting loaded.
Here is my code in firstview.controller.h

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aboutus;
- (IBAction)showabout:(id)sender;
```

firstviewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)showabout:(id)sender {
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self options:nil];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)showabout:(id)sender 
{
 SecondViewController *scv = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:scv.view];
 [scv release];
}
```